# "Add to favorite" function

Tags: uitableview, plist, nsuserdefaults

I need to have such functionality in my app as **"add to favorite"**. I have UITableView with cells, where cell refer to DetailViewController that contains UIImageView. So I need to make such option, when user presses button on the DetailViewController, it goes to FavoritesTableViewController and saves it there. 
I have looked through a lot of questions like this, but I can't figure out what to do as I am newly to iOS programming. 
**Should I use NSUserDefaults?** How to use NSUserDefaults? And If I use it, how can I load saved data in another view controller?
**I have not so many recipes (app of recipes), so can I use plist?** Also I have UIImageView, is it possible to use plist with UIImageView?

Comment: Your recipes have names / identifiers? How are the recipes saved?

Comment: @Wain cells have UILabel that contains name of recipe taken from an array, and details of that recipe shown in another view are images

Comment: Array is hard coded, or in a plist? Because you want to store the recipe name / id. User defaults should be good for this.

Comment: @Wain no, array is not in a plist..

Answer (score 0):

If your recipes don't have identifiers, add them. This could be the name, or the associated image name, but it must be unique and it can't change. This needs to be stored in the recipe data (vehicular I assume is an array of dictionaries).

When you add a favourite, save the identifier in an array in user defaults. The identifier should be a string or a number. Each time a favourite is added or removed, get the array from user defaults, `mutableCopy` it, edit it and then save it back to user defaults.

For the favourites display, pass the full list of recipes (or load it) and then filter it to remove any where the identifier is not in the favourites array.